# Kotlin edit text ; textwatcher for phoneNumber

Tags: android, kotlin, phone-number, textwatcher

i am trying to get a phone number from editText in my project. the problem i'm having;

1 -> the first digit should not be 0.
2 -> unfortunately but I can't delete spaces..

The number format I want to get; (555) 555 55 55
The stage my code has come to;

```
class PhoneNumberMask(val editText: EditText) : TextWatcher {
    var phoneNumber: String = ""
    var isRunning: Boolean = false

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
    }

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
        if (isRunning || s.length == 15) {
            return
        }

        isRunning = true
        phoneNumber = when (s.length) {
            0 -> "test"
            1 -> "($s"
            4 -> "$s) "
            9 -> "$s "
            12 -> "$s "
            else -> s.toString()
        }

        editText.setText(phoneNumber).also { editText.setSelection(phoneNumber.length) }
        isRunning = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your strategy is going to have troubles when the user moves the cursor to the middle of the text field, backspaces, or tries to paste text. What I would try is filtering to only digits each time it's changed and insert parentheses/spaces for the whole string of digits every time. Then put the cursor back where they had it. You can figure out where the cursor should be more easily from `onTextChanged` than from `afterTextChanged`.

Something like this:

```
class PhoneNumberMask(val editText: EditText) : TextWatcher {
    private var isRunning: Boolean = false

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        if (isRunning) {
            return
        }

        var cursorPosition = start + count
        val digits = s.filter(Char::isDigit)
            .dropWhile { it == '0' }
            .take(10)
        cursorPosition -= s.take(cursorPosition).run {
            count { !it.isDigit() } + filter(Char::digit).takeWhile { it == '0' }.count()
        }

        val output = StringBuilder(digits)

        fun punctuate(position: Int, punctuation: String) {
            if (digits.length > position) {
                output.insert(position, punctuation)
                if (cursorPosition > position) {
                    cursorPosition += punctuation.length
                }
            }
        }

        punctuate(8, " ")
        punctuate(6, " ")
        punctuate(3, ") ")
        punctuate(0, "(")

        isRunning = true
        editText.setText(output)
        editText.setSelection(cursorPosition.coerceAtMost(output.length))
        isRunning = false
    }

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your attention. My problem has been greatly improved. back only the first character needs to be 0 and that's what I'm dealing with.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You want to prevent the user from typing 0 as the first digit of the number?

Comment: yes. (542) 555 55 55 must be. user. (054) 555 55 55 shouldn't be able to write that way.

Comment: See the updated code. You can drop initial digits that are equal to 0, which will prevent them from being typed or pasted.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. my problem is solved.